# Combinations of positive integers uniq (order not important)

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations

So, I was searching for a good solution for my problem.

I need to generate(print) all the combination of a list of integers, for example:
if the array contain integers from 0 to n-1, where n = 5:

```
int array[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
```

the order of integers in the combination are NOT important, meaning {1,1,3}, {1,3,1} and {3,1,1} are actually the same combination because they all contain one 3 and two ones.

so for the above array, all combination of length 3:

```
0,0,0 -> the 1st combination
0,0,1
0,0,2
0,0,3
0,0,4
0,1,1 -> this combination is 0,1,1, not 0,1,0 because we already have 0,0,1. 
0,1,2
0,1,3
0,1,4
0,2,2 -> this combination is 0,2,2, not 0,2,0 because we already have 0,0,2. 
0,2,3
.
.
0,4,4
1,1,1 -> this combination is 1,1,1, not 1,0,0 because we already have 0,0,1. 
1,1,2
1,1,3
1,1,4
1,2,2 -> this combination is 1,2,2, not 1,2,0 because we already have 0,1,2.
.
.
4,4,4 -> Last combination
```

For Now I Wrote Code for doing this, but my problem is:
if the numbers in the array are not integer from 0 to n-1, lets say if the array was like this

```
int array[] = {1,3,6,7};
```

my code doesn't work on this case, any algorithm or code for solving this problem,,

Here is my code :

```
unsigned int next_combination(unsigned int *ar, int n, unsigned int k){
    unsigned int finished = 0;
    unsigned int changed = 0;
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = k - 1; !finished && !changed; i--) {
        if (ar[i] < n - 1) {
            /* Increment this element */
            ar[i]++;
            if (i < k - 1) {
                /* Make the elements after it the same */
                unsigned int j;
                for (j = i + 1; j < k; j++) {
                    ar[j] = ar[j - 1];
                }
            }
            changed = 1;
        }
        finished = i == 0;
    }
    if (!changed) {
        /* Reset to first combination */
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++){
            ar[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return changed;
}
```

And this is the main:

```
int main(){
    unsigned int numbers[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    const unsigned int k = 3;
    unsigned int n = 5;

    do{
        for(int i=0 ; i<k ; ++i)
            cout << numbers[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }while (next_combination(numbers, n, k));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must rethink this from the beginning. What is `numbers`? Why does it have five elements when (as far as I can tell) the code uses only three? Where would you store `1,3,6,7`? If `next_combination` finds the kth combination, aren't you doing a lot of work over and over?

Comment: the result combination each time is stored in numbers,, sorry, its not a problem the five elements, my algorithm, is just increasing the numbers starting from zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have working code to generate all combinations of numbers from `0` to `n-1`, then this is very simple.  You have your array of numbers:

```
int array[] = {1,3,6,7};
```

Now, take `n = 4`, because there are 4 items in the array.  Generate all combinations from 0 to 3, and use those as indices into your array.  You now have all combinations of your array values by using all combinations of indices into that array.

Answer (score 2):

This code requires that the "element pool" array be sorted from minimum to maximum, with no duplicate entries.

The function `first_combination` initializes the result array ("dist") to the first combination.  After this, `next_combination` is called in a loop until it returns false (just like in your example).  The "n" and "k" arguments have been replaced with template parameters that pick up the arrays' sizes -- so the enumeration functions need the pool array in addition to the result.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int N, int K>
void first_combination(const T (&pool)[N], T (&dist)[K]) {
    for(int ki=0; ki<K; ++ki) {
        dist[ki] = pool[0];
    }
}

template<typename T, int N, int K>
bool next_combination(const T (&pool)[N], T (&dist)[K]) {
    int ni = 0;;
    int ki = 0;

    for(;;) {
        const int prev_ni = ni;
        // search the pool for the value in this slot 
        for(ni=0; pool[ni] != dist[ki]; ++ni) {
            if(ni == N) return false; // slot contains a value not found in the pool
        }

        if(++ni < N) break;

        ni = 0;
        dist[ki] = pool[0];
        if(++ki == K) return false;
    }

    int v = pool[ni];

    dist[ki] = v;

    // code below assumes pool[] is sorted
    for(--ki; ki>=0; --ki) {
        if(dist[ki] < v) {
            dist[ki] = v;
        }
        else {
            v = dist[ki];
        }
    }

    return true;
}


template<typename T, int COUNT>
void dumparray( T (&dist)[COUNT]) {
    std::cout << '{';
    for(int i=0; i<COUNT; ++i) {
        if(i) std::cout << ',';
        std::cout << dist[i];
    }
    std::cout << '}' << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int pool[] = {1,3,6,7};
    int dist[3] = {0};

    first_combination(pool, dist);
    do {
        dumparray(dist);
    } while(next_combination(pool, dist));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need program for generating [combination (wiki link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Here you have complete description and even ready to use algorithm: http://compprog.wordpress.com/2007/10/17/generating-combinations-1/